# How to design this type of border in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, border

I am new to Android applications. I want to design this type of border.

The design is:

[image]

And tell me which layout and View I should use (GridView, Relative or Linear). Also help me while selection any box the color should change.

Comment: Closing this question as "Needs More Focus". The last sub-question doesn't make much sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView for this

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
         android:background="@drawable/selector" >
    </GridView>
```

Set  `android:numColumns` to your required number.And add selector as  bacground to your GridView

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `GridView`

For this type of border you need a shape:

You need to create 2 shapes and a selector in your drawable folder :

1) For your normal state (un-pressed)

2) For your pressed state

3) Your final shape which will be used as background for your gridItem

1) grid_item_shape

```
/*This will looke like your border without the textview 
  (you can make the textview color blue from your adapter or your layout file) */

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/grid_view_color"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#001414"/>
</shape>
```

2) grid_item_shape_pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffc392"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#001414"/> //choose your own color here
</shape>
```

3) grid_item_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_shape"
    android:state_pressed="false">
</item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_shape_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the blocks (boxes) is variable then you can opt for [GridView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm)

else

go for some Views (TextViews or Buttons) nested inside [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

for selection color you can add a **selector** to **drawable** folder refer [Selector Example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html)